# C# Facebook SDK: Create event with picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, image-uploading

I am using the C# Facebook SDK to do several things on Facebook from my ASP.Net application.

I am able to successfully create an event, but I would like to set the "poster" picture of the event with an image from my website.
This is what I tried but the events are created without an image:

```
var client = new FacebookWebClient(fbAccessToken);
var arguments = new Dictionary<string, object>();

arguments.Add("name", event.Name);
arguments.Add("start_time",  event.Start.ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
arguments.Add("picture", "http://www.mysite.com/images/myEventImage.png");

client.Post("/me/events/", arguments);
```

Is this even possible? I am assuming it is since this guy claims he is doing it using PHP:

http://hasin.me/2011/09/29/working-with-facebook-events-using-graph-api-part-1/

but I haven't been able to do it on my web app.

Thanks for your time!